# @media и абсолютное позиционирование кнопки

Tags: html, css

Не могу подогнать кнопку в нужное место при определенном разрешении монитора, имеется такой код формы поиска,
HTML:

```
<div class="search-box">
                    <form id="quicksearch" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="do" value="search" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="subaction" value="search" />
                        <div class="search-field">
                            <input id="story" name="story" placeholder="Поиск..." type="text" />
<button type="submit" class="btn-login" style="border:0px; padding: 0px; top: 0px; left: 230px;"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button> 
                        </div>
                    </form>
                               </div>введите сюда код
```

CSS:

```
.search-box {width:280px;}
.search-field {width:100%; position:relative;}
.search-field input, .search-field input:focus {width:100%; padding:0 100px 0 10px; border-radius:23px; 
background-color:#fff; color:#333; height:40px; line-height:40px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #e3e3e3;}
.search-box button {position: absolute;}
```

получается все хорошо, как на картинке ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а когда пытаюсь уменьшить по размерам поле для мобильных, вот так:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 470px) {
.search-box {width:180px;}
}
```

то поле ввода уменьшается, а кнопка остается на месте и выходит за пределы видимости экрана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я пытался добавить в @media

```
1) .search-box button{top: 0px;left: 130px;}
2) .search-box btn-login{top:0px;left: 130px;}
3) .btn-login search-box {top: 0px;left: 130px;}
4) .button search-box {top: 0px;left: 130px;}
```

ничего не получилось, кнопка не сдвигилась с места и оставалась за зоной видимости, подскажите, что нужно прописать в медиа запрос чтоб кнопка переместилась на нужную позицию?

Comment: пишите не left:130px; а left:100%;

Comment: Максим Ленский, к сожалению не помогло, кнопка никак не реагирует

Comment: ну конечно не помогло ... padding у вас с права 100px ... и потому ваш блок не 100%

Comment: Звездочка (*) - универсальный селектор для CSS. Соответствует любому тегу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так вроде бы ...если что то не ясно спрашивайте

```css
*{ margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
.search-box {min-width:230px;max-width:300px; margin:auto; border:2px solid #ccc;border-radius:23px;}
.search-field {width:100%; position:relative;border-radius:23px;}
.search-field input, .search-field {width:100%; border-radius:23px;color:#333; height:40px; line-height:40px;border:none; padding-left:4px;}
.search-box button {position: absolute;top:0;right:0;width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:50%;border:none;outline:none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="search-box">
  <form id="quicksearch">
    <input type="hidden" name="do" value="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="subaction" value="search">
    <div class="search-field">
      <input id="story" name="story" placeholder="Поиск..." type="search">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-login"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button> 
    </div>
  </form>
</div
```

Comment: Спасибо так сработало, только мне не понятна Ваша строка кода которая начинается со звездочки(*{ margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}) я не вставлял в мои стили эту строку, так как не понял ее назначение и почему она начинается со звездочки (без нее все работает), и еще вопрос, можно ли border (я поставил у себя толщину 1 px) сделать так, чтоб он якобы сливаляся с кнопкой(входил в нее по краю) а не огибал? еще раз спасибо..